# Как поместить строки файла в массив массивов?

Tags: java

Есть txt файл в котором около 1000 строк. Нужно поместить эти строки в массив массивов по 12 элементов, в последнем массиве соотвественно будет не это число, а остаток. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: читаем файл построчно и заполняем массив в нужном порядке

Comment: Не пойму в каком месте нужно создавать массив стрингов, который будет состоять из 12 элементов и который потом добавим в массив массивов...

Comment: Вы попробуйте начать делать хоть как то. Большая часть вопросов пропадает, если начать делать. Если у вас не получится написать код(когда вы его уже начнете писать), то добавьте его к вопросу и мы поможем исправить ошибки. Лично мне не интересно просто писать код за вас :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadToArray {

    private  static final String FILE_NAME = "1.txt"; // путь к файлу и имя файла
    private  static final String CHARSET = "WINDOWS-1251"; // или UTF-8 или любая другая кодировка
    private static final int INNER_ARRAY_LENGTH = 12;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> resultList = readTextFile(FILE_NAME, CHARSET);

        String[][] resultArray = new String[resultList.size()/INNER_ARRAY_LENGTH+1][INNER_ARRAY_LENGTH];
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;

        for (String string : resultList) {
            resultArray[count2][count1] = string;
            count1++;
            if (count1==INNER_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
                count1 = 0;
                count2++;
            }
        }

        // и теперь выводим в консоль результат
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < resultArray[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("["+i+"]"+"["+j+"]" + resultArray[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    private static List<String> readTextFile(String fileName, String charset) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), charset))) {
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(strLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```